# Challenge: combine into an array only sequential keys of specific value in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want a function that takes parameters like this

```
list = [{a:1},{a:2},{b:3},{b:4},{c:5},{a:6}]
key = :a
combine_only_sequential_occurances_of_specific_key(list,key)
```

and would return this

`[{a:[1,2]},{b:3},{b:4},{c:5},{a:6}]`

Basically, combine a list of key/value pairs that occur sequentially, but limited only to a specific key (or if you like, a set of keys) and preserve order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
def combine_only_blah_blah_blah(list, key)
  list.flat_map(&:to_a).
       slice_when { |(k1,_),(k2,_)| k1 != k2 }.
       flat_map do |a|
         k = a.first.first
         (a.size > 1 && k == key) ? { k=>a.map(&:last) } : a.map { |b| [b].to_h }
       end
end
```

**Example**

```
list = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {b: 3}, {b: 4}, {c: 5}, {a: 6}]
key = :a

combine_only_blah_blah_blah(list, key)
  #=> [{:a=>[1, 2]}, {:b=>3}, {:b=>4}, {:c=>5}, {:a=>6}]
```

**Explanation**

For `list` and `key` above, the steps are as follows.

```
b = list.flat_map(&:to_a)
  #=> [[:a, 1], [:a, 2], [:b, 3], [:b, 4], [:c, 5], [:a, 6]]
e = b.slice_when { |(k1,_),(k2,_)| k1 != k2 }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007f9bda968c50>:each>
```

We can see what elements will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
e.to_a
  #=> [[[:a, 1], [:a, 2]], [[:b, 3], [:b, 4]], [[:c, 5]], [[:a, 6]]]
```

Continuing,

```
e.flat_map do |a|
  k = a.first.first
  (a.size > 1 && k == key) ? { k=>a.map(&:last) } : a.map { |b| [b].to_h }
end
  #=> [{:a=>[1, 2]}, {:b=>3}, {:b=>4}, {:c=>5}, {:a=>6}]
```

The first element generated by `e` that is passed to `flat_map`'s block is

```
a = e.next
  #=> [[:a, 1], [:a, 2]]
```

and the block calculation is as follows.

```
k = a.first.first
  #=> :a 
(a.size > 1 && k == key)
  #=> (2 > 1 && :a == :a)
  #=> true
```

so

```
{ k=>a.map(&:last) }
  #=> {:a=>[1, 2]}
```

is executed. The next element generated by `e` and passed to the block, and the subsequent block calculations are as follows.

```
a = e.next
  #=> [[:b, 3], [:b, 4]] 
k = a.first.first
  #=> :b 
(a.size > 1 && k == key)
  #=> (2 > 1 && :b == :a)
  #=> false
a.map { |b| [b].to_h }
  #=> [{:b=>3}, {:b=>4}]
```

Note that when

```
b = [:b, 3]

[b].to_h
  #=> [[:b, 3]].to_h
  #=> {:b=>3}
```

For Ruby versions prior to v2.0, when [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) made its debut, use [Hash::[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D).

```
Hash[[b]]
 #=> {:b=>3}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is an extremely helpful answer. I feel like I've learned new tools. This is helpful beyond Ruby; it is a lesson in how to think functionally. I was able to solve this procedurally using an array inside a closure; but it felt clunky. This is both informative and elegant. 

Comment: Babak, I am glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the power of [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html), this is a rather easy task:

```
def combine_only_sequential_occurances_of_specific_key(list, *keys)
  list.
    chunk {|h| if keys.include?(k = h.keys.first) then k else :_alone end }.
      # split into chunks by key
    map {|k, hs| if k == :_alone || hs.size == 1 then hs.first else {k => hs.map(&:values).reduce(:concat)} end}
      # transform into hash from key to "sum" (i.e. concatenation) of the values
end

list = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {b: 3}, {b: 4}, {c: 5}, {a: 6}]
key = :a
combine_only_sequential_occurances_of_specific_key(list, key)
# => [{a: [1, 2]}, {b: 3}, {b: 4}, {c: 5}, {a: 6}]
```

Comment: I want to only combine specific keys (or a set of key) not all keys!

Comment: Sorry. I misread that. Well, the modification to do that is trivial.

Comment: Nice! I had a rather procedural rough draft worked out that relied and creating a separate array and pushing on to it. I really appreciate the functional approach in this answer.

Comment: Incidentally, this is the first time ever I figured out a use for the rather strange `:_alone` thingy in `Enumerable#chunk`.

Comment: Cool! I didn't even know it existed.